# Read and Convert KDB Formatted Nanosecond TimeStamp into Pandas

Tags: datetime, pandas, kdb

Please see this CSV extract.

```
Serial  Datetime                        Value
1       2016-09-29D09:15:01.742144000   5.78
2       2016-09-29D09:15:01.742190000   5.78
3       2016-09-29D09:15:01.742222000   5.78
4       2016-09-29D09:15:01.747254000   5.78
```

I need to read in the 2nd column as datetime AND in the nanosecond format as shown above. Using below code without luck.

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from pandas_datareader import data as web
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
data = np.loadtxt("gnca.csv", dtype="int,|S30,|float", delimiter = ",")
date_parser=lambda x: pd.to_datetime(x, format="%Y%m%d %H%M%SS")
```

In the last line above, I am not even sure how to specify the format for the nanoseconds. Note also that the datetime shown above is straight from KDB with the characteristic "D" in between the date and time.

Thanks immensely for any ideas!

Answer (score 3):

IIUC you can do it this way:

```
df = pd.read_csv(file_name, skipinitialspace=True)
df.Datetime = pd.to_datetime(df.Datetime, format='%Y-%m-%dD%H:%M:%S.%f')

In [81]: df
Out[81]:
   Serial                   Datetime  Value
0       1 2016-09-29 09:15:01.742144   5.78
1       2 2016-09-29 09:15:01.742190   5.78
2       3 2016-09-29 09:15:01.742222   5.78
3       4 2016-09-29 09:15:01.747254   5.78

In [82]: df.dtypes
Out[82]:
Serial               int64
Datetime    datetime64[ns]
Value              float64
dtype: object
```